# Which jar to use for SQLite latest version 3.13.0

Tags: sqlite, jdbc

I have downloaded latest SQLite version 3.13.0 from SQLite download page at https://www.sqlite.org/download.html. As per release history, this version is dated 18.05.2016

I am developing an application which uses Java to connect to SQLite database. I have downloaded latest available jar "sqlite-jdbc-3.8.11.2.jar" at https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/downloads. This jar is dated 03-10-2015

My DAO class is as follows :

import java.sql.*;

public class AccountDao {

```
private Connection conn=null;

public AccountDao() throws SQLException {
    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\sony\\Documents\\rough.db");

}
```

I am getting the following error :

*type Exception report
message javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlite:C:\Users\sony\Documents\rough.db
description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
exception 
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlite:C:\Users\sony\Documents\rough.db
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:556)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:462)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause 
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlite:C:\Users\sony\Documents\rough.db
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:916)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:845)
    org.apache.jsp.account_jsp._jspService(account_jsp.java:333)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause 
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlite:C:\Users\sony\Documents\rough.db
    java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    classpackage.AccountDao.(AccountDao.java:19)
    org.apache.jsp.account_jsp._jspService(account_jsp.java:130)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)*

I have added he jar to build path and it is reflected in Eclipse's Referenced Libraries.

Is the above error a problem with using the wrong jar?

Comment: Is the SQLite JAR on your classpath?  Did you include it in the build?  How are you building your project?

Comment: Yes, the SQLite jar is in the class path. I have run System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path")); and the jar is reflected in the output. I may add here that if I replace Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC"); with Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"); and replace conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\sony\\Documents\\rough.db"); with conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe", "rough", "rough"); - it is working fine. I have same data in Oracle and SQLite databases, I am able to connect to Oracle fine but not to SQLite